# How do i read postion data from a different program?

Tags: python

I am working on a python project which uses python osc to read position data from a different app. i don't know how to read the data from a different program. so far my code is just using a random location value that i provide. but i need it to get it from a different. any ideas how to go about that?

```
function printCondition(){
    let caption = "";
    if (element.attr({cx: 100, cy: 300})){
        caption = r.text(120, 300, 'Welcome ');
        caption.attr({
            'font-size': '14',
            'font-family': 'serif'
        });
    }
}
```

so far this is wht i am doing if this makes any sense. i am new to python and have been trying to look online with little to no luck.

so the program i am getting the data from is also controlled by me. it gives me data in the format
(name, Number of users, user ID, X-axis location, Y-axis location, Next user id) and so on.

in my program i want to set it up as when the user reaches a certain (x,y) location, i display something thru a projector. 
does that make little more sense?

Comment: This is too broad - do you control the other program? What does it do with the data? Writes it to a file? Pipe it?

Comment: so the other program uses kinnect to give me location data and i intend to use that data (x and y axis)
it logs number of users and just simply report their location data..

Comment: That sentence adds 0 information. Do you **control** it? If not, **how** does it **give** you the data? Does it write it somewhere? It really doesn't matter how or why it generates said data, only what it is doing with it - I suggest you edit your question to include this information.